# SharePoint | How to highlight duplicates in column?

Tags: json, sharepoint

Is it possible to highlight the same values in the column (duplicates) using JSON in format column? How to lookup these value to be highlighted?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

List Formatting can only look at one row at a time. Unfortunately, this means you can't compare values against other values in the list using formatting.

**Here is a similar case for your reference：**

- [JSON to highlight duplicate column values in SPO List](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d5ca6e6-1071-4ef6-9c92-703294e08245/json-to-highlight-duplicate-column-values-in-spo-list?forum=sharepointgeneral)